Problem when install Ubuntu 24.04 on a GPT disk as a dual boot with Window 10, no USB
I have a problem when trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 on my laptop to dual boot with my preinstalled Windows 10 which was installed on a GPT disk. I don't have a USB (I cannot easily afford one).
When I use Universal USB Installer, my BIOS cannot read my EFI file (boot name not found error when I "add boot option" to choose file).
When I use Unetbootin, and choose the "Hard Disk" option, the only option I have got is the :C drive (which is on a GPT disk). I successfully come to the step where I can choose between UNetbootin or Windows 10 when I restart my computer, but then the following error appears on screen:
Windows Boot Manager  
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."
    
If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \ubnldr.mbr  

  Status: 0xc000007b  

  Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
I use a Dell laptop, have a disk 0 formatted as GPT, disk 1 (an SSD) formatted as MBR. I have searched ChatGPT, YouTube, Facebook, and even on this forum, but I can't follow any of them. How can I fix this?

Please do not use MBR. That is now only required for Windows installed in old BIOS mode, and that should be systems prior to 2012. If you have a blank drive, you can create a 6GB ESP - efi system partition FAT32 with boot,esp flags and extract the Ubuntu ISO into it with p7 zip or similar. That will be UEFI only. Most installers use dd which totally erase a drive as it is a hybrid/DVD/Flash configuration. but how are you backing up data? That is something you must do, unless nothing on system has any value.

@oldfred can you say a little more details, cause I want to do the same but not master in this, first time I install. Also, I don't have a blank drive, I can only shrink on disk 1 or disk 0, and I don't understand much back up data, cause I though shrink the volume will have no effect to the current data...
I also don't have a USB or DVD...

Any change to system has risk. User making an error is often the largest, but software and hardware also can have issues. Backups are important. You say disk 1 & disk 0 so that is two drives?  If you do not have two drives, my method of extracting ISO may work, but any issue & you will not be able to get back into Windows or anything on your system. Then you have to have a repair/recovery Windows flash drive and Ubuntu live isntaller to make repairs, two smaller flash drives.
